# Ubuntu/Gnome3 doesn't directly go to sleep (after being instructed to do so) anymore?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, suspend

So, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, with Ubuntu desktop (I guess):

```
$ env | grep DESKTOP
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
```

I'm also using this extension:

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/

So, up to a month or so ago, if I clicked this suspend ("pause") button, the system would just go to sleep, no questions asked - as I expected it to. Then when the system woke up for sleep, I would have been presented with a login screen, where I'd have to enter my password, to go back to the desktop,

In the past few weeks, though, when I click the suspend button, first I'm taken to the login screen, and then nothing happens. So, I have to "drag" the login screen, then enter my password (as when I log in) - and only *then* does the system go to sleep. Then when the system wakes up from sleep - I'm directly taken to the desktop, without being prompted for a password beforehand.

It seems something "crossed the wires" in the system, so it asks for the password - the one it should ask for upon wake up - right before the system goes to sleep...

Does anyone have an idea what possibly could have broken the original behavior - and more importantly, how can I restore the original sleep behavior?

EDIT: note that `sudo pm-suspend` works - but it doesn't raise/deal with password prompts anyways..

Comment: without that extension.. have you not tried to pressing ALT while hovering on shutdown symbol?

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP - no, haven't tried that - had no idea it works like that `:)` Just tried it - and it just gives me "Cancel", "Restart" and "Power off", no "Suspend" - which is probably why I installed the extension in the first place.

Comment: ya, without installing that extension by default it is `settings` `lockscreen` and `shutdown` symbols, but with pressing Alt the shutdown symbol changes to `pause` symbol.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzmKr.gif did you try this way?

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP, especially for the gif - I tried it, but it doesn't change on my system to "pause", I guess that is because I use the Alt key to drag windows (as in old Gnome), I simply cannot get used to using the Super key for dragging windows. So, I guess I need this extension, if I want to both have a suspend icon, and to use Alt to drag windows. EDIT: if I disable the extension, then I do get that, also with Alt mapped to drag windows! EDIT2: and yes, with the extension disabled, and Alt for suspend, suspend works properly! Thanks again!